# module 'customtkinter' has no attribute 'CTk'

Tags: python, customtkinter

Here is the code i wrote:

```
import customtkinter
app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.mainloop()
```

Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\hp\Desktop\To Do List App\app.py", line 4, in <module>
    app = customtkinter.CTk()
AttributeError: module 'customtkinter' has no attribute 'CTk'"
```

First i expected to show up me the interface and it's just a simple app

Comment: Do you have another script in the same folder named `customtkinter.py`?  *That's* what's getting found by the `import` statement, not the actual module.

Comment: No, I don't,first i confused why this happening to me even though I checked other tutorials I steel have that

Comment: Please share more code from the `To Do List App\app.py` file, you may want to include other files listed in `To Do List App\`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer in case anyone in the future needs help.

The problem is you might be typing 'CTK' instead of 'CTk' with the lowercase 'k.' I know this is not part of the question, but I made this mistake.

If this was the case, made sure the save the file before run it again.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35664296)

Answer (score -1):

From the customtkinter documentation on github there is guidance to update the library whenever possible as it is in constant development.

Try using the command:

```
pip3 install customtkinter --upgrade
```

And see if this solves it. It worked for me.

Link to documentation: https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter